# Oil refinery not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

My oil refinery isn't working. The two red markers at the refinery won't change their color and no energy flows through the pipes. This is my setup (electrical engine is turned off): [image: Refinery][image: Pipes][image: Engine]

This is the new setup changed according to JLaBelle's answer:
[image: New setup]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that the refinery only processes pure (black) oil and not creosote or seed oil.

Answer (score 3):

you have fuel in the oil part of the refinery 
[image: see here]

Oil goes into the 2 containers in the back and refined to fuel which goes into the front container.

to fix this take out the fuel with some buckets, or just destroy and replace the refinery if you dont care for the fuel.

make sure you put oil in the right containers(the back) before refining and extract the fuel from the proper side(the front).

Comment: I've tried that but it still seems not to work...

Comment: on your new screenshot the input/output is still backwards, the input is the 2 containers in the back, it shouldn't have a wooden pipe. Wooden pipes are only to extract from containers and are only one direction (you are effectively blocking off the input by having the wooden pipe there). the output is the front with the markers. the wooden pipe you have attached is the wrong way, flip it. Also to make sure power is even flowing you should see a thin blue line in the conductive pipes while the engine is working.

Comment: I replaced the pipes and now the refinery gets filled in the back. The problem is that the refinery won't accept power. So there is no thin blue line because it doesn't seem to "search" for power even if I turn the engine on. Instead, the line is getting stuck in the first pipe after the wooden one.

Comment: do you have any tools to guage the flow? I'm not sure if a single electrical engine is even enough to power a refinery (they are extremely power thirsty)

Comment: No I don't have such tools but i crafted a multimeter and when I use it at the refinery it reads "Energy requested: 0.0". Hope this helps.

Comment: I would say try moving over to a creative world to get an understanding how the flow of power/liquid is supposed to go. it looks like you have the power travelling a long way to the refinery?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11781/discussion-between-jlabella-and-andalur)